# Need help in converting this Regular Expression to Epsilon NFA

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

good day, can someone help me in converting this regular expression?

$(1*00^+)*$

I know how to convert a regular expression to Epsilon Finite Automata but that + sign besides the second 0 throws me off lol, if someone can explain what that + sign does, it would be great. I can't search anything about it in google because I don't even know what it is called. Thanksss

Comment: Are you sure it's $1^*(00+)^*$, and not $1^*(00^+)^*$?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. It said raised to the power of + in the question, my bad

Comment: $0^+$ is equivalent to $00^*$.

Comment: @Hanemura Can you apply the algorithm now that this has been clarified? This is Lemma 1.55 in Sipser's book in case you're using it.

Comment: @ChubbyChef Yes, I think so, also is it $00^*$ and not $(00)^*$?

Comment: @Hanemura $0^+$ is just shorthand for $00^*$, **not** $(00)^*$.